# WebBrowser control doesn't hold cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, webbrowser-control, console-application

I'm using a WebBrowser control to sign in on a page and retrieve the cookie the response sets in a Windows Console application (C#).

The signing in runs smoothly. I can see in Fiddle that the sign in is successful, and the cookie **is set**. But when I try to get the cookie from the WebBrowser control, the code *webbroser.Document.Cookie* returns *null*.

Here is the code

```
public void runBrowserThread(Uri url)
    {

        var th = new Thread(() =>
            {
                var br = new WebBrowser();
                br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
                br.Navigate(url);
                Application.Run();
            });

        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();



    }

    void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var br = sender as WebBrowser;

        if (!dataInputPassed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(br.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
            br.Document.GetElementById("UserName").SetAttribute("value", "user");
            br.Document.GetElementById("Password").SetAttribute("value", "pass");
            br.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");
            dataInputPassed = true;
        }
        if (e.Url.ToString().Contains("Osiguruvanje") && br.Document.Cookie != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(br.Document.Body.InnerHtml);


        }
    }
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way to get the control's internal WebRequest and retrieve the cookie from there?
Bare in mind that the page I'm signing in to, makes several redirects, one of which, by calling a javascript form submition, thus using WebRequest class won't do much help.

Comment: Try calling [`InternetGetCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384710(v=vs.85).aspx) via p/invoke.

Comment: @Noseratio I'm not sure how to do that. Can you point to an example?

Comment: Kiro, have you searched? There's a lot of samples, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3358086/1768303. With your fiddle, you have access to the names of all cookies.

Comment: Thanks @Noseratio. But I still can't make it work. It returned error code 259 (I assume there are no cookies for the domain). Is there a difference if the cookie is set by an java applet. What if they are stored in a session cookie?

Comment: I believe Sun's Java applet uses a separate and independent cookie container from Microsoft's WebBrowser/UrlMon/WinInet. To get to it, you'd have to install a hook on a low (socket) level, much like Fiddler does. I don't think this'd be feasible option. Is there any alternative to this Java applet, like some AJAX calls? What if this site is accessed from a browser without Java support?

Comment: @Noseratio The web page is not developed by me so I can't do much there. But, would the cookie appear in Chrome Developer Tools, under Resources if the cookie is set by an applet?

Comment: Kiro, I guess it would not but I don't know for sure. I haven't dealt with Java code running off a web page for ages. You can at least try to run this page with Java browser plugin disabled and see if it offers any alternative content.

Comment: If the cookies are HttpOnly cookies then the webbrowser will not store them. See [IEGetProtectedModeCookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196998(v=vs.85).aspx)